# what is the interior of the set in $l^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

$E=\{\{x_n\}:|x_n|\le {1\over n}\}$ inside $l^2$ what is the interior of the set? could any one tell me?

I have checked that the set is bounded,closed, $l^2$ is infinite dimensional so unit ball is not compact. what functional analysis result do I need?

Thank you.

Comment: Let's start here: what does an open ball look like in $l^2$?

Comment: this set is compact so its interior is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $x$ is in the interior of $E$. Then there is $r$ such that for each $n$, $x+re_n\in E$. In particular, $|x_n+r|\leqslant n^{—1}$. Since $x_n\to 0$, we should have $r=0$, which is not possible.